# Why does Initializing char*[] require const while string[] doesn't?

Tags: c++

```
char* c_arguments[] = { "hi","bye" }; //(1)
std::string cpp_arguments[]= { "hi","bye" };
```

(1) gives error in Visual Studio under C++17 standard

> E0144: A value of type “const char*” cannot be used to initialize an
>   entity of type “char *”

If I add `const` in the beginning the code compiles fine.

But why does the first line require const but the second line does not?

How to create `char*[]` without const from an array of string literals?

The code can use features of latest C++ standards and doesn't have to consider legacy systems.

Comment: A string literal is an array of `const char`, so the first requires implicitly converting that array to a `const char *` and then to `char *` - which implicitly discards the `const`, which is not allowed - hence the error in the first case.  Assuming `string` is `std::string` (you haven't specified), there is a constructor of `string` that accepts a `const char *` directly (and the created string contains a copy of the literal passed) so the second succeeds.   In the first case, try adding the `const` to the type of `c_arguments`.

Comment: @Peter yes, I'm using std::string.

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > Conformance mode = "no".

Comment: @HansPassant it magically works. Can you explain a bit? The documentation says "Use this option to  ... make it both more correct and more portable.", by setting to no, I guess my code is less correct. What's going on under the hook?

Comment: Nothing much to say about it, just an option to allow old code to still compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line is calling copy constructors.  Even though the literals are read-only the copies are not.

To create a pointer array to writable strings, you'll have to loop through and create a copy of each literal, just like the `std::string` constructor would do.

Comment: Do you have a One-liner to do what you said for my first line?

Comment: @Gqqnbig: `char* c_arguments[] = { strdup("hi"),strdup("bye") };` will work... but don't forget to call `free()` on each string later to properly deallocate the copies.

Comment: hmm, it becomes so complicated and hard to use. It might be a different topic, but why the main function requires `char*[]`, the hard to use way, not `string[]`. Doesn't the calling function add trouble to itself?

Comment: @Gqqnbig: The parameters to `main()` are provided by an external program such as a shell which has to start software written in any language, so there's no way to use language-specific features such as a `std::string` class.  You're always welcome to write `main()` to do nothing besides convert the parameters and call a `cppmain()` that does all the hard work.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are objects, under the hood, the compiler is creating two `const char*` buffers, and then copying those values into the string objects to give you mutable arrays.  You could do the same to create your `char*` pointers if you wanted.

I wouldn't suggest using literal `char*` pointers without const in C++.  There are a lot of ways to mess them up.  If you want to modify a character buffer you should wrap them in a string and use the appropriate library functions.

Comment: I'm new to C++. By character buffer, do you mean char[]? By wrap them in a string, you mean std::string?

Comment: Yes.  `Char[]` and `char*` are more or less equivalent.  Excluding a corner case - they both point to an address in memory which stores the data of the string.  `std::string` is an object.  When the C++ compiler creates a std::string it will internally create a `char[]` to store the data without it being visible to the user.
The member functions on std::string ( and other library functions ) make strings easy to manipulate without running into the risk of corrupting a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The first type `c_` is an array of pointers to `char`.  The second type `cpp_` is an array of `std::string`s.

When you pass a `"string"` to a pointer, it generates the pointer to the first element.  But the type of the data in `"hello"` is `const`; so a `char*` does not want to point at it.  Instead you need a `char const*`, or a pointer to `const` `char`s.

For a `std::string`, when you pass `"hello"` to it, it *copies* the characters into a buffer owned by the `std::string`.  The copy  can be mutable, so there is no need for `const`.

There are compiler flags that discard the need for `const` when assigning a `"hello"` string literal to a `char*`; they, however, exist for compatibility with code written before `const` was a thing.  Avoid using them.  If you modify, accidentally, the string constant after using those flags, you have undefined behaviour going on (most likely with string pooling you'll cause insanity)

Answer (score 1):

In c++ there are essentially primitive data types and user defined data types.  Primitive data types like int, char, pointers are built into the language. User defined types are built on the top of the primitive types.

Some of C++ user defined types are classes which can do some user defined actions under the hood. `std::string` is such a type. Objects of type string are initialized using a constructor.

All quoted string in c++ are const set of characters, meaning that the program has no right to modify them.

`const char *str = "abc";` just declares a pointer to the constant string 'abc'. Therefore it must be 'const'.

`std::string stdstr = "abc";` declares an object of class `string` from the namespace `std`. The initialization of the object calls a constructor of the `string`. The latter copies the string into internal storage. Copy cannot modify the "abc" character set.  So, there is no conflict.

In the first case you cannot modify the pointer, in other words `str[1] = 'd';` is illegal. it tires to modify the constant (read-only) string directly.  In the second case you **can** modify the *copy* of "abc". `stdstr[1] = 'd';` is legal.